# Android - взаимодействие классов и их методов между собой

Tags: java, android

У меня в проекте есть MainActivity, которое, в общем-то, пока-что ничего не делает, кроме как, пытается вызывать метод isUserAuthenticated класса AuthDashboard.

В isUserAuthenticated лежит следующее:

```
if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            // nothing?
        } else {
            // No user is signed in
            Intent toLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(toLogin);
        }
```

Т.е., перенаправляет на toLoginActivity, в случае, если пользователь не залогинен. При попытке запустить такое приложение - получаю следующее: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object refenrece`

Я пробовал использовать этот код в самом ActivityMain - такой способ работает, но мне это не нравится, т.к. захламляет активити.

Также я пробовал обращаться к пустому методу isUserAuthenticated - и никаких проблем. Но, если совместить этот метод и код - получается такая ошибка, хотя раздельно они отлично работают.

Видел подобные проблемы на этом сайте, однако, они не были решены, поэтому решил задать вопрос.

Comment: В какой строчке возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: `Intent toLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);` - что вы передаёте вместо `this`, когда используете в `AuthDashboard`? Или вы его наследуете от `Activity`, но создаёте экземпляр конструктором?

Comment: Код можете организовывать как вам угодно, но нужно помнить простые правила: новые активити можно запускать только имея экземпляр Context под рукой; экземпляры Context создает только система, самому его создать невозможно, возможно только передать извне через параметр в нужное место.

Comment: чтобы в этом конструкторе `new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);` указывать this в качестве аргумента, класс, в котором вызывается этот конструктор должен быть наследником Context (например активити). иначе вместо this этим аргументом должен быть "живой", созданный системой, Context.

Comment: Thanks, guys! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает в

```
 Intent toLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
```

потому, что вы передаете в Intent ссылку на экземпляр класса AuthDashboard, а не ссылку на контекст. Если вы хотите вызывать интент из своего класса то вы должны передавать в класс, при его создании, контекст. Так же можно передавать контекст только в метод, например:

```
 public void isUserAuthenticated(Context context) {
    if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in
        // nothing?
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
        Intent toLogin = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(toLogin);
    }
}
```

Но лучше не вызывать окна из классов бизнес логики, это создает сложную связанность и в последующем может вызвать проблемы или усложнить поддержку кода.
Используйте делегаты или методы который возвращает значение. Например:

```
public class AuthDashboard {

    private Object user = null;

    public boolean isUserAuthenticated() {
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            // nothing?
            return true;
        } else {
            // No user is signed in
            return  false;
        }
    }
}
```

а в MainActivity использовать так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AuthDashboard authDashboard = new AuthDashboard();
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        if(!authDashboard.isUserAuthenticated()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Понятно. Второй вариант точно сработает, первый тоже хочу попробовать. Сейчас посмотрю.

Также я пробовал делать setContentView(activity_login) из authDasboard (метод isUserAuthenticated) - была та же самая ошибка

Comment: Да, первый способ всё равно возвращает ту же самую ошибку, как я и думал. Если не ошибаюсь, ссылается на метод AuthDashboard, 42 строка, где лежит            startActivity(toLogin);

Comment: Второй способ отлично работает. Спасибо огромное! Я копаюсь в этой проблеме уже около недели, это ужасно. Всё равно интересно, почему и ваш первый способ, и setContentView не работают

Comment: Подобная проблема вылезла и в другом месте. Теперь, уже в LoginActivity, вызывая метод CreateSignInIntent класса AuthDasboard, получаю: could not execute method for android:onClick. Ссылается на строку: startActivityForResult

Comment: Код:
```
    public void createSignInIntent() {

        // Services we use for sign in
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);

        // [END auth_fui_create_intent]
    }
```

Comment: @ДаниилМаслов, все перечисленные вами методы setContentView(), startActivity() и др. - это методы класса Activity или его наследников, они не будут и не должны работать в пользовательском классе не наследнике класса Activity. Возможно вам нужно почитать какую то литературу по Java, чтобы не копаться неделями с такими "проблемами"

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Постараюсь что-то изменить